# T-SQL Join - need to return one row depending on conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

Sorry about the title but I didn't know how to explain it properly.

I have two tables (simplified for explaining):

**Response_Comments:**

```
RES_ID|Comment
------|-------
1     |Test 1
2     |Test 2
{ANY} |Test 3
```

and **Responses**

```
UK|  Name  |RES_ID
--|--------|------
1 |Greg    |1
2 |Bob     |4
3 |Jane    |2
```

And I have written an SQL query to join those tables on RES_ID to append the Comments column to the Responses table. However, I want anything in Response which doesn't have a corresponding RES_ID to get the *{ANY}* RES_ID.

My query is basically:

```
SELECT r.*, rc.comments
FROM Responses r
LEFT JOIN Response_Comments rc
ON r.RES_ID LIKE rc.RES_ID --LIKE, otherwise it complains about int vs varchar
OR r.RES_ID = '{ANY}'
```

However, this returns two rows per person:

```
UK|  Name  |RES_ID|Comments
--|--------|------|---------
1 |Greg    |1     |Test 1
1 |Greg    |1     |Test 3
2 |Bob     |4     |Test 3
3 |Jane    |2     |Test 2
3 |Jane    |2     |Test 3
```

I would essentially like to make my query only return one row per person, and use the corresponding Comment if the RES_ID exists, otherwise use the {ANY} RES_ID comment.

In my actual query I'm joining to about 4/5 other tables and have additional conditions whereby my Response_Comments will have multiple *{ANY}* RES_IDs, but there's other columns that will limit it.

I hope that all makes sense, I'm stumped. This is Transact-SQL by the way, maybe I'll need some CASE thing? Any suggestions?

Comment: Try using `SELECT DISTINCT`

Comment: That doesn't work because the comments are different, so the rows are different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use two `JOIN`s and `COALESCE()` in the `SELECT`:

```
SELECT r.*, COALESCE(rc.comments, rcany.comments) as comments
FROM Responses r LEFT JOIN
     Response_Comments rc
     ON r.RES_ID LIKE rc.RES_ID LEFT JOIN
     Response_Comments rcany
     ON rcany.RES_ID = '{ANY}';
```

You should fix your data structures so the join keys have the same type.  SQL implements foreign key relationships to maintain relational integrity between tables.  Foreign keys should be defined, and they require that the types be the same.

Comment: I will try this and get back to you, but looks like it should work. I originally did have both RES_ID as Integers, but needed to be able to have "{ANY}". I thought about maybe using "0" but it's possible that we already have a 0 in the Responses table.

Comment: @CoreyThompson . . . You might consider `NULL` or `-1`.